# iFrame expands with content but does not shrink

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a cross domain iFrame. The actual iFrame works fine and displays the page at 100% height.

My problem is the first page is around 1200px tall then if you click a link within the iframe and the next page is 800px, you get a 400px blank space at the bottom.

So the iframe gets larger to fit the content but won't shrink. Below is my code:

Code which goes in the page to be iframed:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
</head>
<body onload="parent.postMessage(document.body.scrollHeight, 'http://target.domain.com');">
  <h3>Got post?</h3>
  <p>Lots of stuff here which will be inside the iframe.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Code which goes in to the page receiving the iframe:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function resizeCrossDomainIframe(id, other_domain) {
    var iframe = document.getElementById(id);
    window.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
      if (event.origin !== other_domain) return; // only accept messages from the specified domain
      if (isNaN(event.data)) return; // only accept something which can be parsed as a number
      var height = parseInt(event.data) + 32; // add some extra height to avoid scrollbar
      iframe.height = height + "px";
    }, false);
  }
</script>

<iframe src='http://example.com/page_containing_iframe.html' id="my_iframe"    onload="resizeCrossDomainIframe('my_iframe', 'http://example.com');">
</iframe>
```

Does anyone know how to modify the javascript so it shrinks too?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In your script other_domain equals 'http://example.com' - always. So if you click on 'http://example.com/somePage.html', your function will always return before resizing the iFrame. Instead of equals, you should use

```
if (event.origin.lastIndexOf(other_domain, 0) !== 0) return;
```

Comment: It seems that its a browser issue. My code works fine in Firefox, but does not resize for chrome or safari and does not work at all in Internet Explorer.